# Cassandra is unexpectedly prepending zeros in timestamp millisecond

Tags: cassandra, timestamp

My code is reading data from Kafka and writing it to Cassandra using Spark. But in some cases it is appending the zero in front of millisecond.
For Example-

Kafka Data: `2022-10-11T08:46:12.220Z`

Cassandra Data: `2022-10-11 14:16:12.022000+0000`

Another Example Where we are expecting `2022-07-31 23:28:46.960000+0000` but in Cassandra it is present as `2022-07-31 23:28:46.096000+0000`

How a zero is getting prepended in millisecond and how resolve it? It is only happening in some cases, most of the timestamp are coming correctly.

Note- The difference in hour and minute is due to change in timezone.

Comment: provide information about Cassandra version & other details...

Comment: @AlexOtt show VERSION; outputs `[cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.5 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking at different records because the timestamps you posted are not the same as what you think they should be.

I happen to have a table that contains timestamps and I inserted the same timestamps you posted above and I can confirm that Cassandra is not adding the leading zeros.

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE community.tstamp_table (
    id int,
    tstamp timestamp,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, tstamp)
)
```

And here are the table's contents with the timestamps you posted:

```
 id | tstamp                          | name
----+---------------------------------+-------
  1 | 2022-10-11 14:16:12.022000+0000 | alice
  1 | 2022-10-11 14:16:12.220000+0000 | alice
  2 | 2022-07-31 23:28:46.096000+0000 |   bob
  2 | 2022-07-31 23:28:46.960000+0000 |   bob
```

The CQL timestamp data type is [encoded as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) (Jan 1, 1970 00:00 GMT). Knowing this, we can display the timestamp as an integer value using some native CQL functions:

```
 system.blobasbigint(system.timestampasblob(tstamp)) | tstamp
-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------
                                       1665497772022 | 2022-10-11 14:16:12.022000+0000
                                       1665497772220 | 2022-10-11 14:16:12.220000+0000
                                       1659310126096 | 2022-07-31 23:28:46.096000+0000
                                       1659310126960 | 2022-07-31 23:28:46.960000+0000
```

You should be able to see from the sample data above that the encoded value of the timestamps are correct. For example, the first row is encoded correctly with `022` ms vs `220` ms and the third row is encoded as `096` ms vs `960` ms. Cheers!

Comment: Then It may be issue with the package/library we are using between Kafka and Cassandra.